# Google Maps API to navigate a custom route

Tags: google-maps

I would like to develop a mobile app for cycling using google maps API.
Is it possible to create a custom road network and request routes using only that network?

For example:
https://www.buenosaires.gob.ar/ecobici/pedalea-la-ciudad
Load that information in a custom layer and be able to only get directions using that routes.

Comment: Bicyling Layer is available on Maps JavaScript API which allows you to add bicycle information to your maps using. You can check it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/trafficlayer#bicycling_layer

Comment: Thanka @jabamataro but what Im looking is to have my own layer where I can have custom routes and force google maps to use it to navigate. So far I believe that is not possible.